# Change display order of factors for overlapping data

Tags: r, ggplot2, factors

I have a plot with overlapping points and would like to change which group will be on top.

Please check this example, I manage to invert a and b in terms of colour and order in the legend, with `rev()` but "b" is still on top of "a". Any solution?

Thanks in advance

D.

```
library(ggplot2)

mytable <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 2), 
          y = c(1:10, (1.1:10.1)),
          var = factor(c(rep("a",10), rep("b",10)))
          )

ggplot(mytable) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, colour = var), cex=2)

mytable$var_rev <- with(mytable, factor(var, levels=rev(levels(var)))) 

ggplot(mytable) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, colour = var_rev), cex=2)
```

Comment: it is expected as per the levels of the col variable `var_rev`. If you are expecting differently, please explicitly write what output you have and what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
mytable %>%
  arrange(desc(var)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, colour = var), cex=2)
```

[image]

Just:

```
ggplot(mytable) +
     geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, colour = var), cex=2)
```

[image]

The points are plotted in the same order as in the data frame

Comment: I guess David is looking for points in the plot to be in the same order as labels. They are opposite in your plot. Let us wait to get clarity about the question.

Comment: @Prradep it seemed to me he would like the order of points changed from the original plot so `a` is on top of `b`. Added the original plot.

Comment: @Prradep `b` is on top of `a` in both the OP plots, just the color changes depending on the factor levels.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I don't care much about the legend, just the display on the graph, so the answer from missuse is perfect. Thanks all